# What type of Glue for greenhouse liner?

Tags: adhesive

My grandmother's little greenhouse plastic sheet that was sewn with velcro needs replaced. Unfortunately the sewing machine for it is broke. 
I really need help finding an adhesive that can withstand water, UV and repeated pulling. This is for plastic sheet to velcro trim. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Folks always look for the easy "glue it together" solution for patching things up. Unfortunately I rather doubt that there is going to be any type of adhesive for the types of materials you are talking about that would withstand the type of stress for velcro use. This is the reason almost all velcro that you see fastened to straps, clothing and bags is sewn on.

If the sewing machine is broken you can sew it back together with the tool called the Speedy Stitcher. Search on line, many retailers sell it.

[image]

*(No vested interest in the tool shown above. Just a regular user.)*